# Multiple protractor instances

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I have a web server on our company intranet that will allow users to submit URLs to be tested using Protractor.

All the tests will run on this server, by having PHP write a config.js file for each URL submitted, and using `shell_exec` to run `protractor conf[generated-id].js`.

I'd like run more than one protractor test at a time, in order to process the queue of URLs faster.

These URLs represent different versions of our product so they will be very similar.

Is it safe to run protractor multiple times simultaneously in this way? Is it possible that the tests interfere with each other somehow?

I'm not interested in Selenium Grid given that I want all the tests to run on this machine (2-3 at a time so I want to keep it simple).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding the tests should be self contained and running multiple instances at the same time should not cause an issue.

The rest of this answer makes the assumptions that:

- you are not setting `directConnect`
- the tests to be executed on each browser are the same
- the contents of the conf files being created are the same with the exception of the URL

There are a couple of things that are important to know:

1. If the selenium server address is not specified in the config `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',` then it will be launched automatically and closed when complete.
2. Each browser launched by the selenium server has an associated unique selenium session ID.
3. All actions that are sent to the browser during an automated tests are actually sent to the selenium server along with the session id of the target browser in a command that looks like the following `/session/:sessionId/element/:id/click`. The underlying technology behind webdriver is [the webdriver wire protocol](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) and it ensures that commands only reach the required browser.
4. A selenium server can have multiple active browsers at any time.

That said I'm wondering if there may not be a simpler suitable approach by passing in the URL as a parameter instead. Your tests would use `browser.get(browser.params.targetURL)` and your command to run would be `protractor conf.js --params.targetURL www.URLToUse.com`.

If however, as indicated in your question, the URLs are submitted and simply queued up to be run later then you could write a data driven test which would loop over a list of URL and run the same test on each.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Regarding sending a URL as a param, I ran into issues while trying to specify parameters for third-party plugins that do reports etc